# Erasing old folders when moving folders/files with Robocopy

Tags: robocopy

I am using Robocopy to archive files/folders over X days on our server and am finding that my filters must not be correctly set. The move executes correctly, but the old folders are left on the source server once the move is complete, leaving me with many empty folders and subfolders.
Here is my script:

```
    Robocopy "source" "destination" /DCOPY:T /tee /mt:16 /MOVE /MINAGE:120 /LOG+:Log.txt
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it just me? None of the answers seem to answer the question. The accepted answer doesn't solve the problem as well. There will be many empty directories left in the source directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need /E to copy (empty) subfolders
http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

Answer (score 1):

One problem I have found with some versions of Robocopy is that if you use the /mt switch with the /move switch, it appears to leave behind folders that are now empty.  Try to remove the /mt switch and see if that works better for you since that helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your folder was modified less than 16 days ago, it will not be "moved" (and so deleted) since it does not fit in the filter `/MINAGE:120`.
You may need a routine before robocopy to set the folder's date to the one of the last modified file it contained.

Comment: ``/mt`` has nothing to do with the modification date (you would use ``/min`` and ``/max`` for that), but rather the number of threads to use when copying/moving.

Comment: @XtraSimplicity wrong copy/paste from cmdline of OP. thanks for noticing

Answer (score 0):

The /MT: option has nothing to do with the date, it is the number of threads used by robocopy. The original question remains: if you use robocopy to MOVE a lot of folders with subfolders, the subfolder at the deepest level is indeed MOVED, the folders higher up in the tree remain (albeit empty). This has nothing to do with "by design", it's a bug. In the older versions it worked as expected. If you moved a folder with subfolders 10 levels deep, everything was MOVED. Now the deepest one is moved, all the rest remain as empty folders. Files are moved as expected.
You may remove the /MT switch, it doesn't change anything because the default value of 8 is automatically applied.